# How to remove rows with more than 5 periods

Tags: r, string, filtering, stringr

I have some thousands rows in an xlsx file and I want to delete all rows that have more than 5 periods (Each row is a combination of numbers, letters and periods).

Sample of 3 of my rows in Excel:

> 2a02.587.e815.cb8d.35bf.5c99.8d51.417b
>
> 2a02.587.e815.727
>
> 3a03.5c99.8d51.417b.5212e

I used the following code, but it returns error:

```
library(tidyverse)

    df1 %>% 
       filter(str_count("[.]") >=5)
```

Comment: I have a déjà vu on this question...

Comment: At least this time he kinda provided sample data

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your solution in the same way. Here I first escape `.` with two backslashes to specify referring to a literal `.`:

```
library(stringr)

df1 %>%
  filter(str_count(str, "\\.") <= 5)

# A tibble: 2 x 1
  str                      
  <chr>                    
1 2a02.587.e815.727        
2 3a03.5c99.8d51.417b.5212e
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(str = c("2a02.587.e815.cb8d.35bf.5c99.8d51.417b", 
"2a02.587.e815.727", "3a03.5c99.8d51.417b.5212e")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: thanks, its says "Error in filter(., str_count(str, "\\.") <= 5) : object 'test' not found".

Comment: No test is the name of my data set. You should use the name bound to your data set instead and problem with your solution is that you didn't specify the name of the variable you would like to count `.`s in its values @antonis34 .

Comment: thanks it shows this error now "Error: Internal error in `df_slice()`: Columns must match the data frame size.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
"
I ran this code, since I have 2816 rows `structure(list(str = c(df1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2816L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`

Comment: You can use the data set I shared above and see how I structured the data. It's very simple. Could you share your data set with `dput(head(data))` and your code as well.

Comment: thanks so much, I modified the code a bit and worked, had to think myself how to modify it and Im too dumb with R, thanks again.

Comment: No it's just a matter of experience and you will be fine. You're welcome to ask whenever you have any question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below using `gsub` + `nchar`, which remove all characters except for `.`:

```
df %>%
  filter(nchar(gsub("[^.]", "",V1))<=5)
```

and it gives

```
                         V1
1         2a02.587.e815.727
2 3a03.5c99.8d51.417b.5212e
```

#Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = c("2a02.587.e815.cb8d.35bf.5c99.8d51.417b", 
"2a02.587.e815.727", "3a03.5c99.8d51.417b.5212e")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```

Comment: thanks so much, I modified the code a bit and worked, had to think myself how to modify it and Im too dumb with R, thanks again.